# What is the maximum number of records that a hadoop reducer's reduce() call can take?

Tags: hadoop, lazy-loading, mapreduce

I have a mapper whose output is mapped to multiple different reducer instances by using my own Partitioner. My partitioner makes sure that a given is sent always to a given reducer instance. What I am wondering about is if for some reason, input data is skewed and i get, say, a million records (more precisely, #records can not fit into memory) for a particular key, is there any possible way in which reducer will still work fine? I mean, is the hadoop iterable that is passed to reducer a lazy loader?

Comment: My bad. [hadoop#reducer documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html#Reducer) clearly says, reduce is called once per key. This clarifies my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only practical limit to the values associated with a Reducer is free space on the local disks, both Map and Reduce side. This can be managed by adding more nodes and thus more Map/Reduce tasks, depending on your skew.

So yes, the Iterator loads the values from a combination of memory and disk.